# Is there a way to install Cyanogenmod 7 on the Samsung Infuse 4G?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-infuse-4g

I'm in the market for a new phone (from my faithful Nexus One), and the Infuse 4G looks like a good candidate. I'm shopping for hardware, of course, as software is never the issue with Android. Is there a way to install Cyanogenmod on the Infuse 4G yet? I've always used that ROM in the past as it's by far the best, and I don't want to upgrade the hardware in order to downgrade the software to AT&T bloatware. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Infuse 4G is not officially supported by CyanogenMod yet, there are quite a few Gingerbread (Android 2.3.x) based ROMs for it available on [XDA Developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1161).

An unofficial port of CM7 is currently under development for Infuse 4G.  If you are feeling adventurous, and are somewhat knowledgeable in Linux, you can compile your own version of it from latest sources, as described [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1195525).